# Unity Camera Pan for Second Camera not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As you can see in the title I was making a camera pan similar that of a security camera.

The first camera would pan normally when I press the d button or the a button.
However the second camera didn't pan at all.
In fact even when changing values of the pan, the cameras rotation values, or even the pan limit values nothing worked.

So I hope some people with much more knowledge than me could help me fix the problem.

The code is a modified version of a code from a Brackeys tutorial for a RTS camera.
Since it had a function related to my problem of making a panning camera.

It uses a if statement checking if the camera is enabled and if the a or d button is pressed.
And a Math.Clamp to lock the values of the y rotation of the camera.

```
{
    // Moveable Pan For CAM 2
    Quaternion rotation2 = camera2.transform.rotation;

    if (Input.GetKey("d") && camera2.enabled)
        rotation2.y += PanSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    if (Input.GetKey("a") && camera2.enabled)
        rotation2.y -= PanSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    rotation2.y = Mathf.Clamp(rotation2.y, 180f + -PanLimit.y, 180f + PanLimit.y);

    camera2.transform.rotation = rotation2;

    //Making the Plane holding the Shader Material rotate to the same rotation as the camera
    ShaderPlane2.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90f, rotation2.eulerAngles.y, 180f);
}
```

PanSpeed is 0.3 and PanLimit is 30 on the y axis.

The - and + 180 values are due to the camera being flipped by 180 degreases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to test this because there's still a big chunk of functionality missing from the Question, but it looks like this is an Update method in a script that will be dedicated to the second camera?

One thing to note about Quaternions is that you can't modify the component values as if they were Euler values. So, with that in mind, we can modify your code a little to reflect that, and the assumptions I made earlier.

```cs
        {
            if ( camera2 == null || !camera2.enabled ) return;

            // Moveable Pan For CAM 2
            var rotation2 = camera2.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
            if ( Input.GetKey ( "d" ) )
                rotation2.y += PanSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            else if ( Input.GetKey ( "a" ) )
                rotation2.y -= PanSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            else return;

            rotation2.y = Mathf.Clamp ( rotation2.y, 180f + -PanLimit.y, 180f + PanLimit.y );

            camera2.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler ( rotation2 );

            //Making the Plane holding the Shader Material rotate to the same rotation as the camera
            ShaderPlane2.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler ( 90f, rotation2.y, 180f );
        }
```

But this is for nothing if you haven't determined that this method is even being called. So, we can extend the code by adding the following line before the end of the method:

```
Debug.Log($"New Camera Euler Rotation {rotation2}");
```

You'll then very likely want to get rid of that line after you've determined the code is working correctly.

Comment: Yes this code is from a sperate method which is then called when the requirements( if camera2.enabled = true) are met. I shall try your answer after determining that the method is working correctly.

Comment: All right so I implemented it in my code and the debug says that the value goes from 180.0, 180.1, 180.2, 180.3 and the same goes for when I press a except it goes in reverse as it should (179.9, 179.8, 179.7).

Comment: It seems as if its reading the pan limit value as 30/100 or 0.3. The strange part is that its the exact value of panSpeed.

Comment: @CSSGameDeveloper So it seems like your PanSpeed is nowhere near big enough?

Comment: I presume so ill try changing the value of PanSpeed and report back if it changes the result.

Comment: @CSSGameDeveloper PanSpeed in this case could actually be renamed RotationSpeed, as that's really what you're doing here. And as such, a value of 30 will result in the camera rotating 30 degrees in 1 full second of you holding down a key. To get to 180 degrees would therefore take you 6 seconds.

Comment: Alright I changed it and it only increased its speed. Not the max angle value. ( The value of PanSpeed, I saw your comment after 40 secs)

Comment: @CSSGameDeveloper is that not exactly what you wanted? PanLimit here should be the value you want the camera to stop rotating at. A PanLimit of 30 would allow your camera to move between 150-210 degrees.

Comment: Yes however it Stopped at 180.3 and 179.7 .The max angle I was referring to was the angle that the camera currently stopped. My bad

Comment: @CSSGameDeveloper then try this to find out what PanLimit is `Debug.Log($"New Camera Euler Rotation {rotation2}. PanLimit {PanLimit}");` That should show us what the PanLimit.y value is.

Comment: @CSSGameDeveloper and there's your problem, you either initially set the value of PanLimit to ( 0.0, 0.3, 1.0 ), or your code is dividing it somewhere (by 100 if you think you put 30 as a y value).

Comment: Somehow the code is reading the panlimit y value as 30/100 and z as + 1? Ill attempt to find a where its reading it as 30/100 and z +1. However ill have to do that tomorrow as its quite late in my timezone.

Comment: @CSSGameDeveloper also be aware that if the PanLimit is a Vector3, and you have made it `public` or a serialized private field, then Unity will override what you initially set the value of it in code, with the value it reads from the serialised data.

Comment: The Quaternion PanLimit value is set to nothing ( Public Quaternion PanLimit; )

Comment: But in the inspector I set it to 30

Comment: Okay so I removed the public from public Quaternion and now it works fine.